# Breaker for pool trips but not GFI

Tags: electrical

We have GFI outlet in a "weather proof" box with cover. There is a pump and pool light plugged into it. Every time there is a semi heavy rain, the breaker in the box kicks but the GFI never trips. If the box is letting water in some way, shouldn't it trip the GFI also or just the breaker in the box?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What kind of cover do you have on the box?

Comment: It sounds like water in the box, A small nick in the insulation with some rain could be the root cause. I would open the box next time it trips the breaker if there is water inside drill a small 1/8" hole in the bottom to allow it to drain this is legal up to 1/4"

Answer (score 3):

If the fault is on the line side of the GFCI, then it will not detect it.  A GFCI device only monitors the load side wiring.

They also only protect against ground-faults. If there's a hot to neutral short, a GFCI will not detect it.